# Is there a way to run non web Node.js app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'd like to run non web Node.js batch app on Heroku on schedule. No need to expose endpoints. There is a guide on how to do it using Java https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku

Wondering if someone has done something similar with Node.js.

Comment: So you want to communicate with the Node.js process running on Heroku with HTTP, but without frontend?

Comment: It is a batch job that will run on schedule maybe once a day. No need to have any endpoints exposed.

Comment: This job will then make some HTTP requests towards somewhere than (this is how will it do stuff)?

Comment: Yes, it might. Lets say I want to connect to database to do extracts, or crawl a web page and store the data.

Comment: Well the setup without web part should be easier then with web part. I suggest using npm and heroku-nodejs-buildpack. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using npm and heroku-nodejs-buildpack. [devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)

Put package.json in the root directory. In it you should have:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
},
```

This will tell Heroku to use heroku-nodejs-buildpack (so you don't have to setup that), and will automatically start this script, and get your index.js running.
So this will be your entry point in the application from which you can make everything else you need.

P.S. If Heroku complains that you have not bind to a port in 60 seconds, you can use a server to make a "dummy" bind.

Comment: thanks, it was useful. What about the sleeping time when using the free account? how is this managed? Is it re-started after a sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Not sure to understand what you want to do but Heroku will make it run anyway Node or Java.